# Cannot install extension in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3, setup-wizard

I try to install a extension

Readiness Check --> ok

Create Backup   --> ok

Component Install stay to update pending and console log is empty

Debian v10

PHP 7.1.32

Thank you

Comment: your question is not clear and please describe more

Answer (score 0):

Try to check log \var\log you will find more details there.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure nothing is happening, in my experience it can take a while. You don't want to close the window thinking nothing is happening while it's actually working ;)
Check your logfiles.